# Starting multiple threads in timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I came here for an answer of question which keeps me busy for a longer time.

For clarity, this is what I am doing:

I am creating a java program, which keeps an eye on datas in PLC in form of Graph. Being more specific, I am running a single Timer with TimerTask, which keeps loading data from that PLC every period. But here comes the main problem - a single variable readed from data block takes about 250ms. I want to read more variables at the same time. So basically, it takes variables*250ms in time.
I think that threading here would be absolutely necessary to achieve dreamed goals.

Come little more deeper into the code:

From the beginning. I am starting a Timer as this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(dc, 0, period);
```

Where the dc is instance of a DataCollector class, which gets the data from PLC. A vital fragment of method run() in DataCollector is like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    variables = readFromPlc();
```

And here comes the problem I am standing at. readFromPlc calls read() from another class called TCP. In that class, I am creating as many threads as are variables. But the problem is how to keep those threads running in period of time!. I create those Threads in constructor and at the first time, they of course call run() and properly read datas from plc and show them to a graph. But that's end of those threads - run() won't be called again.

If i could stop and continue threads repeatedly, that would be great. But I am structed here. 
PS: I can't simple make a new instance of TCP, because I have some other methods and functional code there which I don't want to run again.

OR very simplyfied:
I want to run threads' run method every period of time (f.e. every second).

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: You should consider not trying to manage the threads manually, but use a `ExecutorService` instead - particularly, a `Executors#newFixedThreadPool(numVariables)`. You can submit the task that has to be done for each variable as a `Runnable`, and the Threads in this pool will stay alive until you explicitly shut it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, a suggestion about how this *might* possibly be done using an `ExecutorService`

**EDIT/NOTE**: This example only shows the basic approach. In the real application, you'd have to make sure that `shutdown()` is called on the `ExecutorService` once it is no longer required (or alternatively, allow the core threads to time out).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ScheduledMultiThread
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        long period = 1000;

        DataCollector dc = new DataCollector();
        timer.schedule(dc, 0, period);


    }
}

class DataCollector extends TimerTask
{
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int variables = readFromPlc();
        if (executorService == null)
        {
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(variables);
        }

        List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
        for (int i=0; i<variables; i++)
        {
            Runnable task = createTaskForVariable(i);
            tasks.add(Executors.callable(task));
        }
        try
        {
            executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    private Runnable createTaskForVariable(final int variable)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                executeTaskFor(variable);
            }
        };
        return runnable;
    }


    // Dummy implementations
    private void executeTaskFor(int variable)
    {
        System.out.println("Working for variable "+variable);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep((long)(200+Math.random()*200));
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Working for variable "+variable+" DONE");
    }

    private int readFromPlc()
    {
        return 8;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast and valuable answer. I will study more about it and I'll try import this.

Comment: Okay, I implemented this pattern and it just works great. I also discovered that there was a sleep timer in libnodave library (library for working with plc). But it does work as intended! ;-) Thanks.